# converting a graph to a bipartite graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I am reading the application of BFS algorithm. One of the application which i read is to check weather a give graph is bipartite graph or not.Now I want to know, is there any algorithm to convert a graph into bipartite set/graph.

For example we have give a set of edges as

> E={ (4, 1),( 1 ,2), (2 ,3),( 7, 2),( 1 ,5),( 8 ,4), (5 ,8),( 8, 9)}

and set of vertices

> V= { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}

we have to create bipartite set/graph.

Expected output as :-

> s1={1 ,4, 8, 1 ,7 ,3}
>    s2={2, 5, 6, 9}

Comment: You didn't gave a metric to evaluate how well a conversion is doing compared to another one. Can you "delete" as many edges as you want? Otherwise, splitting the vertices in two random substes is always a valid output.

Comment: What do you expect it to do for a non-bipartite graph, e.g. E = {(1,2), (2,3), (3,1)}?  You haven't explained this, and you (or someone) has downvoted the two solutions that attempt to do something sensible in this case, so -1 for you.

Answer (score 1):

The general BFS algorithm to check if a graph is bipartite is:

1. Start from a vertex v_0, and label it s1.
2. Mark all v_0's neighbours as s2, and queue them.
3. Mark all the neighbour's neigbours as s1, and queue them

If, at any point, you get to mark as s2 a vertex already marked as s1 or vice versa, the graph is not bipartite. If, instead, you end up with an empty queue, you are done, and you have your partition.

**EDIT**

If what you want to know, instead,  is how you can build a bipartite graph from a general one, you should first add a metric to compare two different solutions : otherwise, removing all the edges and assigning randomly the vertices to two groups, will always generate a ( trivial ) bipartite graph from any given one.

Comment: What you have answered is only the check whether the graph is bipartite or not. If you need to convert the graph to a bipartite one

Comment: @yasen Sorry, I misunderstood your question. If you are looking for a way to remove some edge to create a bipartite graph, you should give a way to score a solution against another one. Read the comment on your question for more details.

Comment: No, I was pointing out that in the original question the user wanted an algorithm for converting the graph into a bipartite one. What you have answered is only the way to check whether the graph is bipartite or not. If you need to convert the graph to a bipartite one you should simply delete all edges connecting vertices from the same set, no matter if it is s1 or s2.

Comment: @yasen : as i said, without a metric to score what's the best solution, every partition generate a bipartite graph, since there's no requirement in the definition the bipartite graph definition for a vertex to have edges ( aka, remove all edges and group the vertices as you want )

Comment: You are right about that. Sorry for my previous comment, I got frustrated that I hadn't finished it and wasn't able to edit it after 5 minutes so I just made a new one in which I said what I wanted to say in the old one. I think it would be nice if you add the metrics idea in your original answer as it is directly connected to the question asked.

Comment: What about finding a bi-partition in polinomial time in the size of input(n, the number of vertices)? Is it possible? The number of vertices must remain the same and you can delete as few edges as possible.

Answer (score 1):

The *edge bipartization* problem, that is, deleting the minimum number of edges to make a graph bipartite, is NP-hard. [Here](http://www.user.tu-berlin.de/hueffner/slides/dagstuhl05.pdf) are slides of a talk about how to solve it as efficiently as possible.